# browser-sync with webpack not working

Tags: webpack, browser-sync

I'm writing a webpack configuration. I want to build a browser-sync

Here part of the [config](https://gitlab.com/SkipTyler/webpack-config)

```
{...}
sync: require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin'),
{...}
const proxyDomain = 'http://demo.test/'
{...}
 const development = [
                new plugins.sync({
                  proxy: proxyDomain,
                  files: [
                    {
                      match: ['**/*.html'],
                      fn: (event, file) => {
                        if (event === "change") {
                          const bs = require('browser-sync').get('bs-webpack-plugin');
                          bs.reload();
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                })
            ]
```

But on the way out I get this
[error](https://pastebin.com/JPrMEL1p)

What could I do wrong, and how do I fix this error? Thank you!

Comment: I see `Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device`. Free some space on your hard drive.

Comment: I have 4 terabytes of free memory

Comment: $ df -h /tmp
Filesystem  `tmpfs`     Size `2400M`    Used `480K`  Avail  `2.4G`   Use%   `1% ` Mounted on   ` /tmp`

Comment: Why do you look only on `tmp`? Look where your `home` is mounted.

Comment: @Ingaz i have 70G free memory in home, and 79G in root

Comment: Ha! I suppose you're on linux. Look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_common-questions   `"Visual Studio Code is unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace" (error ENOSPC)#`

Comment: You are running out of file handles not disk space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172663/discussion-between-skip-tyler-and-ingaz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I did not copy much the config.

```
 "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --hide-modules --mode development",


const development = [
                new plugins.sync({
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 9090,
                    proxy: 'http://localhost:8080/'
                },
                    {
                        reload: false
                    })
            ]
```